# Indirect in sumproduct not working in this code

Tags: excel, sumproduct

Can someone help me debug the `SUMPRODUCT` function in excel? It won't work when I try to use `INDIRECT` to reference a particular cell.

I rewrote the code for readability:

```
SUMPRODUCT((
    ('<sheet name>'!P4:P9999 = "apples")+
    ('<sheet name>'!P4:P9999 = "potatos"))*
    ('<sheet name>'!B4:B9999 = INDIRECT("C" & ROW()-1))
))
```

Say the value in `=INDIRECT("C" & ROW()-1)))` is `"orange"`
when I enter only`=INDIRECT("C" & ROW()-1)))`, I get the expected value (orange).

If I enter orange directly, the code works:

```
SUMPRODUCT((
    ('<sheet name>'!P4:P9999 = "apples")+
    ('<sheet name>'!P4:P9999 = "potatos"))*
    ('<sheet name>'!B4:B9999 = "orange"))
)
```

But if I put the `INDIRECT` into `SUMPRODUCT`, the output is an error.

Can anyone see my mistake?

Comment: Why use INDIRECT and no just `C1` changing the `1` to the correct first row?  INDIRECT is Volatile and should be avoided if possible.  If it must be relative use INDEX: `INDEX(C:C,ROW()-1)` which is not Volatile.

Comment: And both formula have too many `)`

Comment: I have a series of tables where each table has some text in column C at a different row. So I am going to copy paste this formula a bunch of times. 

Rather than manually change the formula 100 times, it is much more convenient to use ```ROW()-1```, ```ROW()-2```, ect. 

The real code has the correct parenthesis just here I messed up when writing for readability.

Comment: Do you think ```INDEX``` will work in this code, where ```INDIRECT``` did not?

Comment: You know that `C1` will change to `C2` automatically as the cell with the first formula is copied/filled down?

Comment: And I think that INDEX is a better option.  but if INDIRECT is not working, then there is a problem with how it is being used in the actual formula as if it does not work neither will index.

Comment: I'm not moving them down, I'm just pasting from a text editor, so it should be static